# How to copy or move multiple files with same extension?

Tags: tcl

So I am trying to move a bunch of files with similar extensions from /home/ to /root/

Code I tried is

```
file copy /home/*.abc.xyz /root/
```

Also tried

```
set infile [glob -nocomplain /home/*.abc.xyz ]
if { [llength $infile] > 0 } { 
    file copy $infile /root/
}
```

No success.

Comment: https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/file.htm#M30

Comment: not really sure what you are trying to convey here, kindly write clear comments.

Comment: Peter clearly points out a relevant section of documentation: `file copy|rename source ?... source? targetDir`: Multiple sources must be provided as separate arguments. It would rather be your turn to improve your question, for example: "No success." is better elicited.

Comment: You were using a nonexistent subcommand and an argument form inconsistent with other file subcommands, so I pointed out how to write the command you were looking for.

Answer (score 3):

For a 1-line answer:

```
file copy {*}[glob /home/*.abc.xyz] /root/.
```

Comment: How exactly is this an improvement over previous answers, other than inlining `glob`? What if `[glob]` returns empty?

Comment: Since the `glob` here does not have the `-nocomplain` flag, if there is no matching file it will throw an error, which seems appropriate.

Answer (score 2):

Your two attempts fail for different reasons:

1. There is no wildcard expansion in arguments to `file copy`, or any Tcl command, for that matter: `file copy /home/*.abc.xyz /root/`. This will look for a single source with a literal * in its filename.
2. `glob -nocomplain /home/*.abc.xyz` is ok to collect the sources, but `glob` returns a list of sources. `file copy` requires each source to passed as a separate argument, not a single one. To expand a single collection value of source files into a multiple separate arguments, use the Tcl expansion operator `{*}`

Therefore:

```
set infiles [glob -nocomplain *.tcl]
if {[llength $infiles]} {
   file copy {*}$infiles /tmp/tgt/
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `file copy` (and `file rename`) commands have two forms (hence the reference to the manual page in the comment). The first form copies a single file to a new target. The second form copies all the file name arguments to a new directory and this form of the command insists that the directory name be the last argument and you may have an arbitrary number of source file names preceding. Also, `file copy` does not do glob expansion on its arguments, so as you rightly surmised, you also need to use the `glob` command to obtain a list of the files to copy. The problem is that the `glob` command returns a list of file names and you passed that list as a single argument, i.e.

```
file copy $infile /root/
```

passes the list as a single argument and so the `file copy` command thinks it is dealing with the first form and attempts to find a file whose name matches that of the entire list. This file probably doesn't exist. Placing the error message in your question would have helped us to know for sure.

So what you want to do is take the list of files contained in the `infile` variable and expand it into separate argument words. Since this is a common situation, Tcl has some syntax to help (assuming you are not using some ancient version of Tcl). Try using the command:

```
file copy {*}$infile /root/
```

in place of your first attempt and see if that helps the situation.