# Copy multiple files in TCL 8.4

Tags: tcl, tk-toolkit

I saw multiple answers to this question but none of them were specific to TCL 8.4 or prior.

So here's the code that I tried but didn't work:

```
set files [ glob home/*.tcl] 
file copy {*}$files dest/
```

Copying issue is sorted by using eval as one of the comments suggests.
Moving the file should be done with:

```
eval file rename -force $flist dest/
```

Comment: What happened when you tried that? Did it work?

Comment: no, updated the description.

Answer (score 1):

Referring to the 8.5+ solution from [How to copy or move multiple files with same extension?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51409347/how-to-copy-or-move-multiple-files-with-same-extension): There is no expansion operator prior to 8.5.

The example would become:

```
set files [glob home/*.tcl]
eval file copy $files dest/
```

That said, if possible, you should upgrade to 8.5+ (for a number of reasons), but avoiding `[eval]` in such expansion scenarios is advised. Alternativey, you might want to expand by looping explicitly through $files, but this has also a performance downside.

Comment: Out of curiosity, tried using file rename to move instead of file copy to copy. Didn't work, any idea why?

Comment: Sorted. file rename has slight different syntax

Comment: If you're prior to 8.5, you're on an unsupported version of Tcl. Upgrade.